# Allow both packed and unpacked arguments

Tags: python

Is there a way to have methods allow both unpacked and packed arguments? It seems inconvenient to have to always to put `**` before passing a dictionary to methods with keyword parameters. Is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I'd like the both call 2 and call 3 to work.

For example,

```
def my_method(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs["keyword1"])
    print(kwargs["keyword2"])

arguments = {"keyword1": "foo", "keyword2": "bar"}

print("call 1:")

my_method(**arguments)

print("call 2:")

my_method(keyword1= "foo", keyword2 = "bar")

print("call 3")

my_method(arguments)
```

outputs

```
call 1:
foo
bar
call 2:
foo
bar
call 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
    my_method(arguments)
TypeError: my_method() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Is there a way? Yes, but you have to write the function to accept a single (dictionary) positional parameter then wrangle that into the relevant values for the various parameters, inside _every_ function where you do this. That seems more inconvenient to me.

Comment: That would allow the third function call to work, but then the second one does not. It seems like both should be able to work simultaneously. I've edited the question.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you've done without a [mre], but it's perfectly possible to write a function that accepts all three calls (e.g. `def my_method(keyword1, keyword2=None):`, or maybe `def my_method(arguments=None, /, keyword1=None, keyword2=None):`). It's just more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Why is it *so* painful to pass it with `**` that it would be worth the increased complexity? Python doesn't let you define a single function with multiple prototypes, so working around this would be an exercise in ugly heuristics, or ugly prototypes, or other hacky nonsense. Remember, if you ever need to accept any positional args, you'll have a conflict: Is a single `dict` positional argument supposed to be unpacked? Or is it just the value of the first positional argument?

Comment: I guess it's just one more thing to remember when passing keywords. I was thinking to always use named arguements for dicts that are meant to be passed as dicts.

Anyways, I'll bite the bullet and just always use `**` when passing keywords in dicts. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need it, do it like this:

```
def my_method(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        if kwargs:
            raise ValueError('Both positional and keyword arguments present.')
        if len(args) > 1:
            raise ValueError('Too many positional arguments.')
        kwargs = args[0]
    print(kwargs["keyword1"])
    print(kwargs["keyword2"])
```

However, this is not typical Python usage, most Python code doesn't need it.